# resize frame for video in iphone and ipad

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to create an application for iPhone and iPad and my app contains video which not full screen I put the video in a frame with this code

```swift
private func playVideo() {
   guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ch", ofType:"mp4") else {
       debugPrint("video.mp4 not found")
       return
       }
   let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
   let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
   playerController.player = player

   let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
   controller.player = player
   controller.view.frame = CGRect(x: 1, y: 40, width: self.view.bounds.width - 2, height: 280)
   self.view.addSubview(controller.view)
   self.addChild(controller)
   player.play()
}
```

and I set the hight 280 and It is good for iPhone devices

but I want to set the frame hight 550 on iPad devices and can't, anyone help me, thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks for your editing ,Ahmet Sina Ustem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set a calculated height based on device height.

Something like,

```
controller.view.frame = CGRect(x: 1, y: 40, width: self.view.bounds.width - 2, 
                              height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height * 0.66)
```

Comment: Okan Kocyigit It is correctly working,thanks for your answering ,thanks